# Is it best practice to run the reactjs application in apache tomcat server instead of node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, tomcat

Hi I am new to reactjs application I have developed the hello world project .But I want to know what are all advantage / disavantage deploy that application in apache tomcat instead of its own node server . **Does apache makes any thing different in server level optimization instead of node**.Can anyone tell me which is the best apache tomcat or in build node server.

Comment: Although these threads are not specific to `React`, still worth to read => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634299/node-js-slower-than-apache , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346055/can-i-replace-apache-with-node-js

Comment: First of all, you need to understand `Apache server(httpd)` and `Apache Tomcat` are different, All http server faster than other servers that is created to serve dynamic content including nodejs server. I would like to recommend you use http server(Apache, Nginx, etc.) for static content like ReactJS App, Angular App, etc.